# Barcode on Report Align Center

Tags: acumatica

How do I get a barcode to **align center** in a report field?  I have set the `Text Align` and `Sizing` properties both to Center but it still aligns Left.

```
Text Align = Center
Sizing = Center
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with the tools in place. 
BarcodeSettings section allows to put a margin but it won't center the barcode.

You can make a feature request for this here:
https://feedback.acumatica.com/